# Are there any useful parallel data mining applications?

Tags: parallel-processing, data-mining, weka

I am working on a parallel data mining software development project.
I want to find some kind of a data mining software, which can run in a parallel environment with a [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)-like GUI.

Are there any useful **parallel data mining** applications?

Comment: To be sure to understand your question correctly: You are merely interested in a GUI allowing to run DM algorithms with parallelization (and not applications of parallelization in DM research)? Also, your last sentence is confusing because you said Mahout is not that good because it's a "framework", yet you seem to be interested in framework and libraries.

Comment: To add to @chl's question: please elaborate on (1) Whether you mean parallel or distributed, (2) applications or software (your title & text differ), (3) your intended usage, e.g. the data set, (4) the infrastructure available.   Otherwise, the general answer is "Yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you try? There are *tons* of data mining applications around. Isn't rapidminer parallel and uses Weka?

Try these applications:

http://www.kdnuggets.com/software/index.html